# Local Procedure Bindings

Tags: syntax, scheme, lisp

I'm new to Scheme and Lisp in general, and upon learning I've stumbled upon a cryptic syntax used in local procedure binding:

```
(define mock
    (lambda (s) 
      ;; this is what I don't understand
      (let splice ([l '()] [m (car s)] [r (cdr s)])
        (append
         (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) r)
         (if (null? r) '()
             (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))))
```

It took me a while to grasp that `splice` is a scoped procedure with 3 arities. Rewriting this in an ML-esque style it seems to produce similar output:

```
(define mock2
    (lambda (s)
      ;; define `splice` first
      (define splice
        (lambda (la lb lc)
          (append
           (map (lambda (x) (cons lb x)) lc)
           (if (null? lc) '()
               (splice (cons lb la) (car lc) (cdr lc))))))
      ;; bind `splice` and its arguments together and call it with them
      (let ([sp splice] [l '()] [m (car s)] [r (cdr s)])
        (splice l m r))))
```

The second version is a bit longer and somewhat look more imperative, but defining `splice` as a normal procedure inside the scope before binding it in parallel with the arguments (or just chuck them in as-is) and calling it looks saner.

Question is are these two versions replaceable? If yes, could you help explain the first version's syntax of binding local variables (`l`, `m`, and `r`) within the `splice` binding form?

Comment: Shouldn't you return L when reaching `(null? r)`: it seems it is never used otherwise.

Comment: @coredump yes you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `splice` is like re-entering a loop, which is what it is there for. A tail call is a goto anyway. It is often named `loop`, instead of thinking up some special name for it.

"looks saner" is debatable, and actually with Schemers you'll lose this one, because this is a very popular Scheme construct, called *"named let"*. It is usually re-written with `letrec` btw, if/when one wants to rewrite it, to understand it better. Internal `define` can be used as well, but then, why not use `(define (mock s) ...` in the first place.

So, the usual way to re-write this

```
(define mock                              ; or: (define (mock s) ...
    (lambda (s) 
      (let splice ([l '()] [m (car s)] [r (cdr s)])
        (append
         (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) r)
         (if (null? r) '()
             (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))))
```

is this:

```
(define mock
  (lambda (s) 
    (letrec ([splice (lambda (l m r)      ; or: (define (splice l m r) ...
                       (append
                        (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) r)
                        (if (null? r) '()
                            (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))])
      (splice '() (car s) (cdr s)))))
```

and writing it in the *named let* way saves one from having it defined in one place and called in another, potentially far away. A call  enters its body from the start anyway, and named let better reflects *that*.

This is pretty self-explanatory. The transformation from one form to the other is purely syntactical, and both can be used interchangeably.

Comment: With your pointer I finally found the doc http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Iteration.html. Seems like it is a special form that binds the name to a procedure. Is this something that can be accomplished with `do`?

Comment: the re-write will be much more involved with `do`, which is itself a macro anyway, most probably. `letrec` is regarded as one of the most fundamental building blocks in Scheme.